# Openstack X-auth-token and token

Tags: openstack

I use this shell:

```
(1)curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/v2.0/tokens -d '{"auth":{"passwordCredentials":{"username": "changzhi", "password":"dddddd"}}}' -H "Content-type: application/json"
```

And in http.log I find a instance:

```
(2)url -i -X GET http://10.0.3.139:35357/v3/projects -H "User-Agent: python-keystoneclient" -H "Forwarded: for=10.0.3.139;by=python-keystoneclient" -H "X-Auth-Token: 04ef789a010c6f252a9f572347cac345
```

Q:In (1), I can get a long json string. It include token.id . But I don not know what the difference between X-auth-token in (2) and token.id . Could someone tell me the difference ?Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first query is against the endpoint for port 5000, it is handing back a user token.

The second query is against the endpoint for port 35357, typically set up as the management endpoint for Keystone. So that token will be different, plus the call is against /projects not /tokens.

You can pass X-auth-token as a header for subsequent http requests, but realize that admin tokens and user tokens offer differing access to resources.

Answer (score 0):

Keystone services are provided by 2 endpoints, one having port 5000 and other being 35357.
35357 port offers admin related operations whereas port 5000 offers general API functionality.

Tokens can be Scoped (for specific Project/Domain) or Unscoped (generated just with username/password).
When you request a Token using v2 api , you receive tokenId in the response whereas in v3 api the tokenId is in response header for key : X-Subject-Token.

You need to provide X-Auth-Token in every API request . You can also use super user in X-Auth-Token header. Super user token is present in keystone.conf (admin_token key)